# Can't compile .d.ts TypeScript files in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm trying out TypeScript for the first time and I've downloaded the angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped package from nuget but I cannot generate JavaScript files from it.

I've tried deleting the file, creating a new TypeScript file (called angular.ts) and this generates a JavaScript absolutely fine with the exact same code. I could keep this file and do the same with the others but it seems like I should be able to compile these sorts of files.

I've also looked into the Properties of my project and under TypeScript Build I have the following options activated:

1. ECMAScript version: ECMAScript 5
2. Compile on Save
3. Allow implicit 'any' types
4. Module system: none
5. Keep comments in JavaScript output
6. Generate source maps

I don't have any errors when I build my project and all of my other .ts files that I have added all generate JavaScript files without an issue. I've looked to see if this is a known Visual Studio issue but I can't seem to find much about it. Is there a setting for this or should it happen automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstood the question but you cannot compile `d.ts` files. When you see a `d.ts` file, you can think of it like a interface for a project that was not written in TypeScript.

For example, I use phaser game engine.  So like everyone else, I go and get the phaser.js file.  At this point, my TypeScript cannot understand this phaser.js file.  So, I go and grab the phaser.d.ts file and it is that which contains the full API of the phaser.js.

So basically, `.ts` files will always compile to JavaScript, whereas `.d.ts` are the definition files providing the bridge to using a `.js` file!

Comment: Ah ok I didn't realise that. So in other words you need to have the normal .js file of the library (say jquery.min.js for example) as well as the .d.ts file?

Comment: Yep! Exactly. When you use a library which is raw JavaScript in a project. The first thing you want to do is go and find a `d.ts` file for it.  Think of these files as just helpers for your development process. They are never published, and they never have implementation. They exist to bridge the gap between existing libraries and typescript.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Typescript with Visual Studio in our app, but we also had some problems when trying to coerce VS 2013 to compile TypeScript to JavaScript. We opted out for [Grunt plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-typescript) and no longer rely on VS. I suggest you do the same. One caveat: don't use `watch` in typescript Grunt task. It will trigger VS into infinite loop when you will be building your project. Instead when you apply  changes to your .ts files, tab switch to command line and run grunt task for ts->js compilation.

Comment: TypeScript is apparently fully integrated into VS 2013 so it seems strange that an issue like this appears. Thanks for the link